# cannot install or import pyodbc

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-import, pyodbc

I am using both python Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.4.5. but I am working with Python 3.4.5

There are two users on this server. one user able to import pyodbc without issue. but other account not able to access pyodbc module.

```
-bash-4.2$ python3
Python 3.4.5 (default, May 29 2017, 15:17:55)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

Below is pip version

```
-bash-4.2$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /<path to lcaotion>/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages 
(python 3.4)
```

when try to install pyodbc

```
pip3 install pyodbc==3.0.10
```

Getting below error

```
    -bash-4.2$ pip3 install pyodbc==3.0.10
    Collecting pyodbc==3.0.10
    Using cached pyodbc-3.0.10.tar.gz
    Installing collected packages: pyodbc
    Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yygzbf28/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4w_3g87z-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/tmp
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/tmp/pip-build-yygzbf28
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/tmp/pip-build-yygzbf28/pyodbc
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/tmp/pip-build-yygzbf28/pyodbc/src
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.10 -DPYODBC_UNICODE_WIDTH=4 -DSQL_WCHART_CONVERT=1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-yygzbf28/pyodbc/src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/tmp/pip-build-yygzbf28/pyodbc/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
In file included from /tmp/pip-build-yygzbf28/pyodbc/src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
/tmp/pip-build-yygzbf28/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:41:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Below packages are installed in server

```
dbus-python.x86_64
libselinux-python.x86_64
newt-python.x86_64
python.x86_64
python-backports.noarch
python-backports-ssl_match_hostname.noarch
python-configobj.noarch
python-configshell.noarch
python-decorator.noarch
python-devel.x86_64
python-ethtool.x86_64
python-iniparse.noarch
python-kmod.x86_64
python-libs.x86_64
python-pcp.x86_64
python-pycurl.x86_64
python-pyudev.noarch
python-rtslib.noarch
python-setuptools.noarch
python-slip.noarch
python-slip-dbus.noarch
python-urlgrabber.noarch
python-urwid.x86_64
python2-crypto.x86_64
python34.x86_64
python34-libs.x86_64
python34-pip.noarch
python34-setuptools.noarch
rpm-python.x86_64
```

AND also when I tried to install as sudo permission I am getting below

```
 sudo pip3 install pyodbc==3.0.10
 Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc==3.0.10 in 
 /export/home/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is unrelated to PIP

> fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

You are missing your GCC (C++/C Compiler) and Development Tools from your machine - hence the missing C header file

You can install the following YUM group to satisfy the requirement:

RedHat / CentOS:

```
sudo yum group install "Development Tools"
```

or

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Comment: -bash-4.2$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

Comment: Try `yum install python3-dev`

Comment: -bash-4.2$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
but one user in the server can access the pyodbc module but when I try to install using sudo in shows as below  sudo pip3 install pyodbc==3.0.10
Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc==3.0.10 in /export/home/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages

Comment: [Check out this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-7-redhat-linux-install-gcc-compiler-development-tools/)

Comment: You are missing your headers for GCC

Comment: this is working fine for other users how could that happen